# how to save data in editText using Shared Preferences in android

Tags: java, android

i have two edittext i want to save data in edittext until i have not change it how to made it . i try some thing like this but data not save.

```
e1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    e2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);

    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String homewifi  = e1.getText().toString();
            String officewifi  = e2.getText().toString();

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

            editor.putString(HOMEWIFI, homewifi);
            editor.putString(OFFICEWIFI, officewifi);
            editor.commit();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Thanks",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

when activity open again data not show in edittext.

Comment: you are saveing data but not retrive data

Comment: @Masoom Bacha see my answer bellow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not retrieving data from  **sharedpreferences** modify code like this:

```
 sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);  
     SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

    e1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    e2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    String homewifi = sharedpreferences.getString(HOMEWIFI, "");
    String officeWifi = sharedpreferences.getString(OFFICEWIFI, "");

    e1.setText(homewifi);
    e2.setText(officeWifi);


        b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);

       Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String homewifi  = e1.getText().toString();
                String officewifi  = e2.getText().toString();



                editor.putString(HOMEWIFI, homewifi);
                editor.putString(OFFICEWIFI, officewifi);
                editor.commit();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Thanks",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
```

Comment: see here i have a issue little

Comment: @MasoomBacha YES TELL ME WHAT IT IS?

Comment: if(con.getSSID().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("\"Ranksol\"")) here i am using manual string value which working fine

Comment: i want use string value which i get from edittext

Comment: String homewifi  = e1.getText().toString();

Comment: homewifi how to write it in brace where is ranksol?

Comment: @MasoomBacha  It means you have save value as Ranksol and when you retrieve from  sharedpreferences you have to set in editText as "Ranskol" ( with " quotes ) , right ?

Comment: no no Ranksol is manual string value i want to set string value which i get from edittext

Comment: e1.getText().toString(); this is save string as whatever you put inside the editText so you don't have to take care of that . while retrieve it will give result as previously saved both are completely same as previously saved

Comment: can i also save spinner in shareprefrence

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114178/discussion-between-suhas-b-and-masoom-bacha).

Comment: @MasoomBacha click on chat link so We discuss more and solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

> when activity open again data not show in EditText.

Need to get data from `SharedPreferences` and call `setText` method of `EditText's` to show it when starting `Activity` Again.like:

```
....
e2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
if (sharedpreferences.contains(HOMEWIFI)) {
   String strHomeWifi = settings.getString(HOMEWIFI, "default value");
   e1.setText(strHomeWifi); 
}else if (sharedpreferences.contains(OFFICEWIFI)) {
   String strofficewifi = settings.getString(OFFICEWIFI, "default value");
   e2.setText(strofficewifi); 
}
...
```

Comment: where should i put this code in onclick?

Comment: @MasoomBacha: no check my answer . do it before `b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {` line in your code

Comment: e1.setText(strHomeWifi);    here what is the str

Comment: @MasoomBacha: whole code is `String strHomeWifi = settings.getString(HOMEWIFI, "default value");
   e1.setText(strHomeWifi);`

Comment: @MasoomBacha: is there any issue in that line?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you forgot to set string from your SharedPreferences to both the edittext,

after saving it from edit text to sharedpreferences.

like

```
 e1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
            e2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);

            sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(sharedpreferences.getString(HOMEWIFI))){
                e1.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(HOMEWIFI));
            }
            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(sharedpreferences.getString(OFFICEWIFI))){
                e1.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(OFFICEWIFI));
            }

            b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String homewifi  = e1.getText().toString();
                    String officewifi  = e2.getText().toString();

                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

                    editor.putString(HOMEWIFI, homewifi);
                    editor.putString(OFFICEWIFI, officewifi);
                    editor.commit();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Thanks",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
```