# Can't save the data from EditText

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-edittext

I have some problem with saving the text from an EditText.

Here is the code:

```
String lista;
EditText bevasarlolista = null;
bevasarlolista = view.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.bevasarlo);

if (items[position] == "Bevásárlólista")
{
    Button mentes = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.hozzaad);
    bevasarlolista.Text = lista;

    mentes.Click += bevasarlolistaMentese;
}

private void bevasarlolistaMentese(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lista = bevasarlolista.Text;

    Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, bevasarlolista.Text, ToastLength.Long).Show();
}
```

So the problem is that when I write something in that editText, and than press the 
'mentes' button the toast text appears, but its empty, meaning that my editText is empty too and i don't know how sould i save the editText.text

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Shared preferences example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example)

Answer (score 0):

To make a text blocked you have to change the code like this:

```
String lista;
EditText bevasarlolista = null;
bevasarlolista = view.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.bevasarlo);

if (items[position] == "Bevásárlólista")
        {
    Button mentes = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.hozzaad);
    bevasarlolista.setText(lista);

    mentes.Click += bevasarlolistaMentese;
}

private void bevasarlolistaMentese(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lista = bevasarlolista.Text;

    Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, bevasarlolista.Text, ToastLength.Long).Show();
}
```

Embedding the text in java This is an overview. For more information, see this link [how to save data in editText using Shared Preferences in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37717303/how-to-save-data-in-edittext-using-shared-preferences-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

So it turned out that i was just being dumb.

i sould have given value to the edittext inside the if()

**BAD**

```
string lista;
EditText bevasarlolista = null;
bevasarlolista = view.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.bevasarlo);

if (items[position] == "Bevásárlólista")
     {

     }
```

**GOOD**
    string lista;
    EditText bevasarlolista = null;

```
if (items[position] == "Bevásárlólista")
     {
         bevasarlolista = view.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.bevasarlo);
     }
```